# OpenGL bindless textures and seamless cubemap filtering

Tags: opengl, texture-mapping, opengl-4

Seamless cubemap filtering is a useful feature to filter simple skyboxes or lightprobes for PBR. It has been present in OpenGL for quite a while.

However, it does not play nice with bindless textures. The `GL_ARB_bindless_texture` specifications says:

> When accessing cube map textures using texture handles, the seamless
>   cube map enable is ignored and treated as disabled.

What is the canonical approach to ensure seamless filtering for cubemaps accessed via bindless texture handles?

Comment: The extension seems quite clear this isn't supported (probably the dynamicness of bindless textures makes implementing seamless filtering annoying in a way driver authors did not want to deal with). I would think the answer is, you don't?

Comment: @Andrea: "*probably the dynamicness of bindless textures makes implementing seamless filtering annoying in a way driver authors did not want to deal with*" That seems unlikely. Vulkan always uses seamless cubemap texture access, so it makes no sense that OpenGL couldn't do that. I mean worst case, the bindless texture extension could just say that it behaves as if filtering is always seamless, just like Vulkan.

Comment: @NicolBolas what would be a good approach to emulate seamless cubemap filtering programmatically via GLSL?